# xargs with shell function doesn't work

Tags: xargs

I'm using shell function like `zip0 () { zip -0rq "$1" "$1"; }`

And I wanted to use it with xargs like this.

```
$ seq 1 3 | xargs zip0
xargs: zip0: No such file or directory
```

But as the error message shows, it doesn't recognized as a command.
How can I use `xargs` with shell function?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158564

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to have xargs invoke the shell:

```
seq 1 3 | xargs sh -c "zip0 () { zip -0rq "$1" "$1"; }; zip0"
```

Comment: If it is so complex to use shell function with xargs, I'd write shell script for it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ironsand still useful when sending remote scripts for execution with ssh.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it (the fn) visible by exporting it and using a sub-process (bash) to call it:

Watch out for the use of  `“{}”` mentioned in comment. I needed it and it’s in a controlled environment.

In my scenario I can’t write aux bash scripts in files as this is sent to a remote host with read only fs. So functions help. I’m sending a literal bash script to ssh command, that contains functions, exports them then run commands, pipes output to xargs and call the functions with `bash -c`

```bsh
17:19:07-me@dsk:~/tests$ cat /tmp/bashtest && /tmp/bashtest
01: function decompressAndGrep () {
02:   echo "Juan"
03:   echo "$(echo $zstdCmd -dc $1) | grep -m3 -A20 -i '\[ERROR\].*customer.*'"
04: }
05: export -f decompressAndGrep
06: decompressAndGrep "Pepe" 
07: find ./ -name '*.zst' | head -n1 | xargs -n 1 -P 4 -I {} /bin/bash -c "decompressAndGrep {}"

## Output:

# Inner Call (line 06)
Juan
-dc Pepe | grep -m3 -A20 -i '\[ERROR\].*customer.*'

# xargs Call (line 07) see `-I {}` and it's use later "decompressAndGrep {}"
Juan
-dc ./juan.zst | grep -m3 -A20 -i '\[ERROR\].*customer.*'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [Never embed `{}` in the shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).